# Sort Array and Re-generate in Angular to page components

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

I have a few things I'm trying to accomplish with interesting/cool results if I can get it to work - This is actually OLD JavaScript code that I wrote and am now trying to data bind it to UI Page components in Angular.

I'm using Angular Material FAB buttons to generate 4 Random Numbers to the buttons (it looks cool!)

My first problem is, I don't know how to sort them from lowest to highest.
The numbers come out like this on top of the cool round Fab buttons:
(https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples )
"25 11 19 50", when they should come out like: "11 19 25 50"

```
<md-card class="alternate-theme">   
  <md-list id="tpList">
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let tp of randNumbers" (click)="randNumbers = tp">
      <button md-fab color="primary">{{tp.ball1}}</button>
      <button md-fab color="primary">{{tp.ball2}}</button>
      <button md-fab color="primary">{{tp.ball3}}</button>
      <button md-fab color="primary">{{tp.ball4}}</button>
      <button md-fab style="background-color: #e91e63;">
        <md-icon style="color: white" ng-click="reGenerate()">loop</md-icon>
      </button>
    </md-list-item>   
  </md-list> 
</md-card>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with angular-cli, or the tag "command-line-interface"?

Comment: So generate numbers in your component class, store it in an array, sort it there and use result in *ngFor loop